# How to add custom ripple effect color to ListTile in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In flutter by default, `ListTile` has the grey ripple effect color. But there are situations when we need to change the default ripple effect color. There is no property in `ListTile` that can help you in that.

Here is the sample of the default ripple effect color.

[image]

**So how can anyone change the default ripple effect color in `ListTile`.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no property in the `ListTile` that can help you in getting the custom ripple effect color. So to get the custom ripple effect color you have to wrap your `ListTile` with the `InkWell` widget.

In `InkWell` widget there are many properties like `splashColor`, `hoverColor`, `highlightColor` or `focusColor`, that can help you in getting the custom ripple color of your choice.

**NOTE: When you wrap your `ListTile` with the `InkWell` widget, you have to specify the `onTap` property of the `InkWell`. Otherwise without `onTap` property your `InkWell` widget won't be able to apply custom ripple effect color.**

***Here is a code sample to show the example:***

```
Card(
  child: InkWell(
    splashColor: Colors.blue,
    onTap: (){},
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text('Your Title Text Goes Here'),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
      ),
     ),
   ),
```

**Here is an output of the sample code:**

[image: Test Sample]

Comment: Use can also use the Material Widget instead of Card :-)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(splashColor: Colors.red),
  child: ListTile(
    title: Text('Hello World'),
    onTap: () {},
  ),
)
```